# How to revert draggable element on failed ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

i have a element of images that i want to be able to be able to drag to a droppable zone, and fire a ajax post request but if it fails the draggable element should revert back to it's place.

Also how do i find which was the droppable zone that the element was drop inside, i know how to find that item that was dropped but not the zone it was dropped in.

However as i am new to jquery, i am having problems getting this to work. my code for now is as follows

```
$(function() {
    $(".drag").draggable( { revert:"invalid"} );
    $(".drop").droppable({
        accept: ".drag",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var imageId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
            var targetLocation= 'something'; //no idea how to find zone dropped into
            var formdata={id:imageId};

       $.post( "<?php echo base_url('home/test'); ?>", { image_id: imageId })
      .done(function( data ) {
        var status = $.parseJSON(data);
        // console.log(status['status']);
        if (status['status']=='success') { 
            failure= false;
            $(ui.draggable).hide("slow");
         }
      },'json');          

        }

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this` keyword in the [drop](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) call back to refer to the droppable to which item is being dropped.

For reverting you can use a flag in the [revert](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert) callback as given below:

```
$(function () {

    var failure = true; // this will be used to indicate whether to revert or not

    $(".drag").draggable({
      start: function(e,ui){
        failure = true; // reset the flag
      },
      revert: function () {
        return failure;
      }
    });

    $(".drop").droppable({
      accept: ".drag",
      drop: function (event, ui) {
        var imageId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
        var targetLocation = $(this); // this will refer to the droppable
        var formdata = {
            id: imageId
        };
        url: uploadURL,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (data, ui) {
            status = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (status['status'] == 'success') {
                $(ui.draggable).hide("slow");
                failure = false;
            }
            // if the condition is not met, revert will return true,and item will be reverted
        }
     }
    });

});
```

*Side note*: for this to work, we've to make the ajax request synchronous(*not the best way to do it, but at test it's does the job*)

Comment: Hi thanks for your input, but could you tell me where i have my syntax error as i cannot find it

Comment: don't you have an extra `})`   after closing the success callback..?

Comment: Hi, i tried your code but even on success the image would revert to it's original position before the hide animation would play. This is akin to behavior of failure. Is there anyway to stop the image from reverting on success?

Comment: @user3148070 did you double check the ajax response is success..? becusue when i checked this is working fine... or can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something where it does not work..?

Comment: Yes i have double check the response, it is correct. Will do up a jsfiddle if i can

Comment: It seems that is it during the ajax post call that the action reverts back. With out the ajax post call the function works. But when i am using ajax post call the image would revert to its original place before it hides itself

Comment: @user3148070 that's probably an issue with the value returned by your ajax request. the solution works fine as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fL4Eb/)

Comment: I would think that could it be due to the "lag" time that it takes for the server to reply, the behavior is as such. However i would mark your answer as a solution.

Comment: @user3148070 Wait, don't mark it as accepted, because it doesn't solve the issue. The request being asynchronous is the issue, can you try setting `async: "false",` for the ajax request..?

Comment: Thanks , setting async to false fixed the issue. Could you update your answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `start` and `stop` property events in jQuery's draggable.  Something like the following:

```
$(".drag").draggable ({
    start: function(event, ui){
        var top = ui.position.top;
        var left = ui.position.left;
        $(this).attr({"data-top": top, "data-left": left});
    }
});
```

The above will save the start location of the element you just moved to the DOM.

In your AJAX error handling section, change what you have

```
}else{
     // revert the drag option
    $(".drag").draggable( { revert:"invalid"} );
};
```

to

```
}else{
    var top = $(ui.draggable[0]).attr("data-top");
    var left = $(ui.draggable[0]).attr("data-left");
    $(ui.draggable).css({
        top: top,
        left: left
    });
}
```

We use the `ui` parameter passed into the function associated with the `drop` property to grab the `top` and `left` values that we saved on the DOM.  We then change the CSS `top` and `left` values of the element itself

Answer (score 0):

In drop write the following code

```
    if (!ui.draggable.data("originalPosition")) //fix the original position 
                        {

                            ui.draggable.data("originalPosition",
                            ui.draggable.data("uiDraggable").originalPosition);

                        }
```

and write the following function anywhere and call any function in else

```
 function revertsingle($selector) {
    position = $selector.data("originalPosition");
    if (position) {
        $selector.animate({
            left: position.left,
            top: position.top
        }, 500, function() {
            $selector.data("originalPosition", null);
        });
    }

 }
```

and pass the selector to that function

```
   revertsingle($("#id"));
```

thats it...